# Issue with Push Notifications from PWA to Devices in China, Seeking Guidance on Implementation

Tags: push-notification, progressive-web-apps, baidu, great-firewall-of-china

I am working on a Progressive Web App (PWA) and have encountered a challenge related to sending push notifications to devices located in China. While researching potential solutions, I came across recommendations to use push.baidu.com.

However, after reviewing the documentation, several uncertainties persist:

1. Does push.baidu.com effectively handle the task of sending push notifications to devices in China?
2. Does it support integration with PWAs (Progressive Web Apps)?
3. How can users be subscribed to receive notifications, as this information seems to be missing from the documentation?

I would appreciate any insights into the usage of push.baidu.com in the context of PWAs, as well as alternative approaches to achieve push notifications in China. Thank you in advance for any guidance or recommendations!

I tried to utilize push.baidu.com based on recommendations but faced difficulties in understanding its full implementation, especially concerning PWA integration and user subscription for notifications.